# AEM 6 integration with Adobe Target problems

Tags: aem, test-and-target

I am integratign AEM 6 with Adobe Target and have some problems with it.

Particularly, when I add "Adobe Target Mbox" component on the page - T&T request is sends but in console there is an error :

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

I found that it throws when `mboxOfferDefault.prototype.show(content)` function is called from /etc/clientlibs/foundation/testandtarget/util/source/init.js.

The problem is that this function calls `this.hide(content)` which doesn't exists in `mboxOfferDefault.prototype` and that's why I suppose this error is thrown.

Can anyone tell me why this function in init.js is overriding default `mboxOfferDefault.prototype.show(content)` defined in mbox.js and what will be the risks if i'll remove this function from /etc/clientlibs/foundation/testandtarget/util/source/init.js ? 
I will be appreciated if some one will help me with this problem.

Thanks!